# Assembly - Get extern label address

Tags: assembly, global, extern, att

Extern labels(refers to code or data, does not matter) are labels not found in the current source file and referenced later with the linker. Can I get the address of many extern labels(pointing to code) that are declared consecutively. Also, those labels are actually a macro.

Explaining it with example:

I have a source A.asm with the **macro** declared as **global**:

```
.macro label n
.global label\n
label\n:
push (n)
ret
```

And a source B.asm, with some *label(s)* marked as **extern**:

```
labels_array:
.extern label0
.extern label1
```

Can I get the address of each *label* with `mov` or `lea` starting from `labels_array`?

Like this:

```
mov $labels_array, %ebx #label0 here
mov 4(%ebx), %eax       #label1 here
```

If not, is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: `.extern` doesn't do what you think it does. In fact [it does nothing](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Extern.html) (assuming you are using GNU _as_). You want `.int`. Even then the `mov $labels_array, %ebx` does not give you `label0` it gives you its address.

Comment: As far as i know, .int reserves 4bytes of space setting there a value. What does .extern do?

Comment: As I said, and even linked the manual for you, it does nothing. Since you want an array containing the label addresses, you want to reserve 4 bytes and set a value (assuming you are on 32 bit).

Comment: Label 0, 1... are code, not data, i need the address, but, what i am getting? The address of the label itself or the address to the extern directive label(unlikely)?

Comment: Okey, extern is ignored in GAS. Then what about the addresses?

Comment: The array is data. What the labels are, is irrelevant. If you want an array of addresses, you want `.int label0, label1`.

Comment: @Blackburn The label is the address.  If you e.g. do `mov $foo, %eax` you obtain the address of label `foo` into `eax`.  I am very confused as to what you are looking for.

Comment: Okey, @Jester, is clear now. You can post the answer if you want, i will aprove it now. Thanks